# ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName and type conversion

Tags: powershell

Let's imagine I have this function:

```
function Get-HasFoo{
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromPipeline=$True,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [bool]$Foo
    )
    process {
        Write-Host "`$Foo is $Foo"
    }
}
```

If I specify explicitly my arguments, it works:

```
Get-HasFoo -Foo $true
$Foo is True
```

However, if the value comes from a CSV import, it does not:

```
$payload = ConvertFrom-Csv "Foo
True
False" 

$payload | Get-HasFoo
```

I get this error :

> Get-HasFoo : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Foo'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only 
>   Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.

Is there a way to autoconvert values from a csv import?

**[edit]** My actual goal is to feed PowerShell functions from CSV files (edited with Excel). Functions can have several arguments.

**[Edit]** I also tried to bound csv to a custom type:

```
$typeDef = "public class HasFooDef {
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
}"

Add-Type $typeDef

$payload = ConvertFrom-Csv "#TYPE HasFooDef
Foo
True
False"
```

But the error subsists

Comment: what are you trying to do ? here $payload is a psobject with one property : foo and 2 values : true and false. This cannot be cast to a boolean

Comment: @Kayasax: no, payload is an array of custom PSObject with one property `Foo`: `$payload | % { $_.Foo }` outputs `True\nFalse`, and `$payload -is [array]` outputs true. `Foo` property is of type string, but I can ensure it contains only true or false.

Comment: $payload.foo.count = 2

Comment: @Kayasax, this is due to a nice feature of powershell that allows to project a subproperty of an array of object to a new array with only this property values

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` produces a list of objects with *string* properties, which won't play nice with your *bool* parameter. You need to convert the strings to actual boolean values to make the output work with your function:

```
$payload = ConvertFrom-Csv "Foo
True
False" | Select-Object @{n='Foo';e={[Convert]::ToBoolean($_.Foo)}}

$payload | Get-HasFoo
```

Comment: Yep.  I was expecting PowerShell to convert the strings to boolean, but even passing strings on the cmdline explicitly fails:   `get-hasfoo -Foo "true"`

Comment: While this should work, this would a pain to write, compared to the simple `Foreach-Object` construction, with `[bool]$_.Foo` within

Comment: @SteveB Except that `[bool]$_.Foo` doesn't do what you apparently expect it to do.

Comment: hum, you are right : `$payload | % { Get-HasFoo -Foo ([bool]$_.Foo) }` returns `True` twice, instead of `True,False`

Comment: @SteveB That's because casting a string to a boolean isn't the same as parsing the string representation of a boolean value. The former is based on the length of the string (empty strings evaluate to `$false`, non-empty strings to `$true`).